# calculate number of 'Real' days between two dates when given a number of business days as input

Tags: bash, function, date

This isn't as simple a question as you may think... I've looked at the other questions an as far as I know, none are related...

I'm trying to devise a bash function that when given an input that is the number of business days between now and the past, it works out how many 'real' days (ie weekdays and weekends) are between them (public holidays are outside the scope of this so the the 25th Dec for instance is just another day for the purpose of calculation).

That is to say:

My input is 10 Business days ago from NOW (03/02/2021) how many 'real' days is that?

So looking at the calendar, 10 business days ago was January 20th. So the answer that the function needs to spit out is 14

I was able to think of 'an' algorithm that, when given small gaps seems to work, but then fails miserably when number of business days gets larger and for the case of Jan and early Feb had to include a manual 'fix' for dates spanning into 2020.

The rough idea is get the rough difference in week numbers and then multiple by two and add to the original inputted number... (through trial and error I realised if the year boundary is passed the 'past' week number is higher than the current week number so still do the math but the ABS(res) was off by 10, so add 10 to the offset to compensate (add because the offset in this case would be a minus number).

```bash
get_date_offset(){
    local bdays="$1"
    local res="$1"
    newday="$(date --="$bdays days ago" "+%A")"
    if [[ ${newday,,} == "sunday" ]]; then
        bdays="$(( bdays + 1 ))"
    fi
    week_num_now="$(date +%W)"
    week_num_past="$(date --="$bdays days ago" "+%W")"
    offset="$(( (week_num_now - week_num_past) * 2 ))"
    if [[ $week_num_past > $week_num_now ]]; then
        res="$(( res + (offset + 10) ))"
    else
        res="$(( res + offset ))"
    fi
    printf "%d\n" "${res#-}"
}
```

Now, this works for small business day inputs, so if I ran

```bash
get_date_offest 10
```

The answer printed IS 14 (ie 14 real days when counting weekends).

but it breaks down if I have an input say of 26 (if 3rd Feb is NOW, - 26 business days = 29th Dec) it kicks out a number 2 two small... and if I have to keep adding `if [[ ]]; then` statements in to add random additional number depending on some random combinations of days and week nums then the algorithm is wrong (I felt the edge case with the year changeover was acceptable to do so, but if there are 50 different things I need to manually tweak).

Any thoughts as to an algorithm that is not broken like mine!

The ONLY input is a number that represent the number of business days to look backwards but things following this need the input as number of 'real' days to look backwards, and both of them need to match calendar wise.

**ANSWER:**

Thanks to Dijkgraaf I have the following function:

```bash
get_real_days(){
    busdays="$1"
    weeks="$(( busdays / 5 ))"
    weeks_7_day="$(( weeks * 7 ))"
    weeks_mod="$(( busdays % 5 ))"
    res="$(( weeks_7_day + weeks_mod ))"
    day_num_now="$(date +%u)"
    day_now="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
    if [[ $res -le 5 ]]; then
        day_number_now_minus_res="$(( day_num_now - res ))"
        if [[ $day_number_now_minus_res -le 0 ]]; then
            res="$(( res + 2 ))"
        fi
    fi
    res_day_date="$(date --date="${day_now} - $res days" +%Y-%m-%d)"
    day_num_res="$(date --date="$res_day_date" +%u)"
    if [[ $day_num_res -ge 6 ]]; then
        res="$(( res + 2 ))"
    fi
    printf '%s' "$res"
}
```

I'm sure I could make it more 'concise' but for readability I prefer slightly more verbose breakdowns of the steps.

Comment: Take the business day, divide by 5 and make at an integer, multiply by 7, and add the modulus of business days and 5.  E.g for 26/5 => 5 (weeks) * 7 = 35 + 1 (modulus of 26 and 5) = 36

Comment: @Dijkgraaf can I ask a stupid question...... how did you think/know of that? Genuinely interested in the logic of creating good algorithms (will no doubt help in future endeavours).

Comment: @Dijkgraaf does that algorithm work for business days < 5?

Comment: Also, randomly, when you say make an INT is that like floor INT (ie extract the whole number portion regardless of the decimal so 7.8 = 7 etc..) or regular rounding (.5 and above rounded up etc.)

Comment: Yes, Floor for int or a DIV function.   For under 5 days  you will need some logic to check the day of the week for your current and to see if it does cross a weekend or not.  As to how I came up with that, simply that a business week is 5 days and a calendar one is 7 days and I worked it out from there.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf could you create that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I found a minor issue... say I'm running a script on a Monday and I want 4 business days hence, your algorithm would suggest the answer is 4, but on a Monday, 4 business days hence is 6 'real' days... It seems the algorithm works for ALL business days including and above 5, but below 5 it needs some additional checking of the current day...  so if 4 or less and day is Monday through Thursday add 2

Comment: Yes, as I said earlier, if it is 5 days or less, that algorithm won't work, you have to check the current day and see if you cross the weekend or not and add 2 if it does.

Comment: ahh sorry yes I misread the comments (more than once!!) all done!

If you could copy your comment into an answer I can select it as an answer and mark the question solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For business days over 5 days you can take the business day, divide by 5 and make at an integer (floor), multiply by 7, and add the modulus of business days and 5. E.g for 26/5 => 5 (weeks) * 7 = 35 + 1 (modulus of 26 and 5) = 36

For under 5 days you will need some logic to check the day of the week for your current and to see if it does cross a weekend or not, and add 2 if it does.

Comment: Sorry I feel like a total nooob now..... sorry for stupid questions.. 

The script is run once per day, and needs to convert business day to real days relative to the day the script is run.

There is an issue with the algorithm when running on certain days of the week as when the number of 'real' days is calculated the answer lands on a weekend not the desired day.

I added and additional check to see if the current day - the initial result is a weekend, if so, add an additional 2 to the result. that seems to work....